# Directed graph where each node must contain all elements from source nodes

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

I'm looking for a directed graph data structure where each node is unique and contains a set of elements (at least one).
Each node must contain all elements from nodes pointing to it so it possible to walk from each root node and visit all supersets.

[image]

I actually only need insert and walk operation, but I struggle to cover all the edge cases when inserting a new node.

I was wondering if there is a common name for this data structure / problem?

Comment: Such graphs are called [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You can use DFS for walk operation and or create a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) using it.

Comment: Do you want to insert a new root node and update the rest of the nodes on the basis of it?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami

There is no need for topological sorting, because when the graph properties are fulfilled you can use DFS or BFS to visit all supersets from selected root just by following edges.

The idea is to add a new node so the graph properties are still valid - parent contains all elements from its children. Think of it as an index

Example 1. Adding node ABC would require inserting ABC between AC -> ABC ->ABC, AB -> ABC -> ABCD and BC -> ABC -> ABCD.

Example 2. Adding node CDE would require only C -> CDE